# Error of calling WCF service

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-7

I have built a server with WCF service: IService.cs and Service.cs. The code of the files are following below:

Iservice.cs

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ITaiKhoanNguoiChoi
{ 
    [OperationContract]
    void InsertStaff(string username);
 }
```

Service.cs

```
public void InserStaff(string username)
        {
            try
            {
                conn = new SqlConnection(strConnect);
                conn.Open();
                cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into STAFF values('" + username+ "')", conn);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }
```

ok, that is all code of Service which I have built. Then, I will call the serveice at my client, the code look like:

```
ServiceClient proxy = new ServiceClient();
private void btnInsert_ManipulationStarted(object sender, ManipulationStartedEventArgs e)
        {
            proxy.InsertStaffCompleted += new EventHandler<AsyncCompletedEventArgs>(InsertStaffMethod);
            proxy.InsertStaffAsync("John");            
        }

void InsertStaffMethod(object o, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e) 
        { 
            MessageBox.Show("YAY!");
        }
```

Now, in the first time I click btnInsert, "YAY" will be showed 1 time.

In the second time I click btnInsert, "YAY" will be showed 2 times.

....

In the N th time I click btnInsert, "YAY" will be showed N times.

That is my problem. I don't understand the reason why I just click 1 time, the InsertStaff method at server will be called many time.

Could you explain for me about that. And how to solve the problem. I just want InsertStaff method to excute only time when I click btnInsert 1 time.

Answer (score 1):

It's a while since I worked with WebForms event lifecycles, but I think that the EventHandler is being added on each click of btnInsert, so more and more events are being fired each time.

The solution is not to have the line

```
proxy.InsertStaffCompleted += new EventHandler<AsyncCompletedEventArgs>(InsertStaffMethod);
```

in the button click handler.

Create proxy and then add the event handler once in the form load event.

As an aside, if this will end up as production code beware of the possibility of SQL injection in the line:

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into STAFF values('" + username+ "')", conn);
```